# How to avoid containing duplicate static framework?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcframework, static-framework

I want to create xcframework to wrap cocoa pods framework for my customer.

I created project for it, and created PodFile to install one framework, and implement some function and run script to create my custom xcframework.

The cocoa Pods framework contained StaticFramework, I could create it, but, the size of it was big compared to in case of using other DynamicFramework  cocoaPod framework.

In addition this, I created App project, and import my custom framework and cocoa Pods framework to the project.

The size of IPA was so big, I wondered the IPA may contain 2 Static Framework(in my framework, and cocoa Pods framework)

Is it possible to resolve this issue?

Is it possible to avoid containing static framework when I create my custom framework?

Comment: Regardless you create a dynamic or a static framework, as long as you ship them with your app, the size should be the same. So, if the size is the one that matters to you, dynamic vs. static won't help you much.